# Asynchronous Server Socket error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

I am using msdn Asynchronous Server Socket Example. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

On this server i am getting data in string format from a device.

The problem is after some time of getting data successfully i get below error and application hang:-

**socket exception was unhandled:
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.**

c# debug shows error in this part of code.

```
listener.BeginAccept(
      new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
      listener);
```

how  to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, server established connection with the client and start sending the data. If this is right than server created socket, bind it and start tcp transmission correctly. Afterwords server destroys the socket due to exception, and connection is lost.

All I can think of is that this problem is related to the message size. You can check buffer-size, and the time-out intervals.

Answer (score 0):

To help resolve error:
Verify you are not having network issues. 
Confirm the remote host is not closing the connection (most common cause of this error). 
Confirm you are providing a sufficient backlog to handle all your users:

```
listener.Listen(100);
```

where 100 = the maximum length of the pending connections in queue.

You can catch the remote host disconnect in your ReadCallback:

```
SocketError errorCode;
int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar, out errorCode);
if (errorCode != SocketError.Success)
{
    bytesRead = 0;
    //handle remote host disconnect...
}
```

If these all check out, then you may have issues else where in your code. You may need to post more details about how you create, start, stop your listener and how the remote host is handling the connection.

Comment: If the remote host(device) is closing the connection, then how to handle this. The code is same as posted at msdn. Check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx